# STM32 SPI, can't get it working

Tags: spi, stm32, nucleo

SOLUTION: CubeMX set the MOSI pin to be on another bus/port on the nucleo board (not sure why). Setting MOSI to the required GPIO pin manually worked.

I'm trying to set up a basic SPI interface using the HAL provided by ST on the STM32F767ZI nucleo board. What I am currently trying to do is to write anything to the SPI bus and view it using an oscilloscope to confirm I have it working. The code I'm using is follows:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <TFT.h>
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);


int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();

    uint8_t xy[4] = {0x23,0x45,0x7A,0xE6};

    begin();
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1);
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)xy,4,1000);
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
        HAL_SPI_DeInit(&hspi1);
    }
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 108;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.I2c2ClockSelection = RCC_I2C2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
    hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
    hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
    hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
    hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
    hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_SOFT;

    HAL_SPI_MspInit(&hspi1);

    if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
     PD8   ------> USART3_TX
     PD9   ------> USART3_RX
     PA8   ------> USB_OTG_FS_SOF
     PA9   ------> USB_OTG_FS_VBUS
     PA10   ------> USB_OTG_FS_ID
     PA11   ------> USB_OTG_FS_DM
     PA12   ------> USB_OTG_FS_DP
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : User_Blue_Button_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = User_Blue_Button_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(User_Blue_Button_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PF12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD3_Pin LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : STLK_RX_Pin STLK_TX_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = STLK_RX_Pin|STLK_TX_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : USB_SOF_Pin USB_ID_Pin USB_DM_Pin USB_DP_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_SOF_Pin|USB_ID_Pin|USB_DM_Pin|USB_DP_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_OTG_FS;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_VBUS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_VBUS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_VBUS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif
```

An oscilloscope capture of the infinite loop yields the following result where yellow is SCK and blue is MOSI for SPI1 (CN7 pins 10 and 14 for the nucleo-f767zi). The number of clock cycles is consistent with the 4 bytes being sent using the transmit function however there is no actual data on the MOSI pin.

[image]
Any ideas what could be missing here?

UPDATE:

The `HAL_SPI_MspInit()` function appears in `stm32f7xx_hal_spi.c` and `stm32f7xx_hal_msp.c`. The first one looks like this:

```
__weak void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(hspi);

  /* NOTE : This function should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
            the HAL_SPI_MspInit should be implemented in the user file
   */
}
```

The last one looks like this:

```
void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(hspi->Instance==SPI1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA5     ------> SPI1_SCK
    PA6     ------> SPI1_MISO
    PD7     ------> SPI1_MOSI 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
```

I am fairly certain that the last one is being executed since a break point within the function triggers. I am not sure what the other two are intended for.

Comment: Have you verified the jumper settings and pin mappings?

Comment: I am certain I am probing the right pins for starters, and I don't think the jumpers affect SPI1 in any way from what i can see. Don't think there is an error in this regard.

Comment: There are couple of SPI bus on CN7. Which is being selected? Do you have any ther code, which just works with the same board? to make sure ,you are doubting more on the HAL then the hardware.

Comment: I am sure I have the right SPI bus since the SCK is oscillating and the pins are labelled on the silkscreen. I've tried building a project with just the SPI functionality enabled (no I2C etc.) and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Are you able to see the data in the data registers in disassembly window? What is the state of chip select pin?

Comment: This is what I see in my disassembly for SPI1: [link](http://i.imgur.com/tafPybT.png) 

I am incrementing the variable xy by 1 each loop iteration but I can't see anything incrementing in the I/O registers. What should I be looking at?

Comment: Have you tried it with SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES?

Comment: Yes, no effect :(

Comment: Can you add oscilloscope capture to your question?

Comment: Please post the contents of your HAL_SPI_MspInit() function - it is the one where the SPI pins and clock ar initialized. CubeMX definitley generated one, not sure in which file though.

Comment: Okay I have found 3 of them defined in 3 separate .c files that are in my project space, I have updated them in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I can see one problem for sure which is HAL related. The `HAL_SPI_Transmit` is not a ready to use function. It is a blocking SPI send function only without the blocking part.

So I do not know if there anything else wrong, but you certainly should wait after the SPI transmit as follows:

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &xy, 1, 1);
while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
```

You should wait for the end of the transmission, before moving on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I assumed it was tied up in the function itself. I've added it for good practice, but doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Init33 Where do you initialize the GPIOs for the SPI?

Comment: @Init33 And where do you enable the SPI clock?

Comment: I thought that cubeMX would have included the initialisation of GPIO for SPI in it's skeleton code, but apparently not? I've added `HAL_SPI_MspInit(&hspi1);`to the start of the `MX_SPI1_Init()` function which should initialise low level SPI GPIO and clock but it's still not working. Main code updated*

Comment: @Init33 Sorry you are right `HAL_SPI_Init` should call `HAL_MSP_Init` which will init the GPIO and enable the clock. I forgot that and just looked for the code.

Comment: @Init33 Try using `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &xy, 1, 1000);`. So increase the timeout value, though 1 byte should be transmitted in less the 1 ms but one could never know.

Comment: I modified the code a little, still nogo.

Comment: @Init33 Note that this is wrong `(uint8_t*)xy` while`&xy` was right. The first one will cast `0x35` to pointer and send some random value from `0x35` memory location.

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit the xy variable which is now an array, I think the typecast pointer is now correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to change **HAL_SPI_Transmit** to **HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive**. I Had similar problem and with my particular SPI configuration (which was pretty much the same as yours) only HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive worked for me.

I wanted to add it as a comment, but have to low reputation for that. Sorry.